# Two images are not on the same level

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I am using the following code to put two figures next to each other (I am not providing a minimal example right away, because maybe the problem is obvious from the code. However, I will, if someone needs one!):

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pdfexp.png}
\caption{Dichte der Exponential-Verteilung für  $a=0.5,\ \frac{1}{3},\ \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{1000}.$}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cdfexp.png}
\caption{Verteilungsfunktion der Exponential-Verteilung für $a=0.5,\ \frac{1}{3},\ \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{1000}$.}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

This produces:

[image]

The images are of the same size, but the axes are not at the same base level. The axes from the right figure are put higher than the ones of the left figure. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please always use the provided method to include images. This insures that they don't disappear after a while.

Comment: If the bounding box of the separate images (`pdfexp.png` and `cdfexp.png`) have the same bounding box, then it would be possible align the baselines of the chart. Otherwise you'll have to fiddle with their vertical placement using `\raisebox`.

Comment: There is no `[h]` option for `minipage`, is there? Try `[t]` (top) instead. I think this happens because the one caption is higher. Top alignment to the baseline of the first line (i.e. the images) might fix it.

Comment: t fixed it, you guys are the best!

Comment: Easiest solution is to set `height=4.3cm` or similar rather than width. If necessary you can adjust slightly the second or retake thecapture. (Avoids minipages as well).

Comment: A comment on your code not related to the (invalid) [h] specifier for minipage positioning: In the captions, try `$a=0.5$, $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{5}$, und $\frac{1}{1000}$.` instead of the current `$a=0.5,\ \frac{1}{3},\ \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{1000}.$` Basically, you should have four synctactically separate math formula "particles," and the sentence-ending period should *not* be placed inside a math formula since it belongs, syticactically speaking, to the surrounding sentence rather than to the fraction that precedes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `[h]` option for `minipage`. You should use `[t]` (top) to align both minipages to the baselines of their first lines, which are the images.
The misalignment happens because the one caption is higher and the `minipage`s are center-aligned be default. The unknown `[h]` option is silently ignored, but might break the alignment altogether.

Another thing is that you have 2x `0.5\linewidth` plus `\hspace{0.5cm}` which is of course to wide. I would recommend to use `0.49\linewidth` and `\hfill` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your example you are building out two boxes, each with the graphic and its caption inside. That means that the bottom point of the graphic is somewhere inside and not accessible to any alignment mechanism.

Due to the fact that you use `\begin{minipage}[h]` (which is invalid but unfortunately doesn't give an error) you effectively and up with the default which is `\begin{minipage[c]`. But even `[t]` or `[b]` wouldn't really help as you are interested in aligning at the graphics bottom.

A simple solution to achieve your goal is to forget about `minipage`and instead use a 2-column `tabular` environment where the graphics and the captions are each in their own cell.